# The meaning of "debt-strapped" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "debt-strapped" in the following text?

> Adverse trends are no less troubling. Within the Western world,
>   economic inequality threatens social peace. **Debt-strapped** governments
>   are patching up costly welfare systems that struggle to meet their
>   promises. Disappointed voters are abandoning the centre-right and
>   centre-left for newly sanitised extremes. Outside the slowed and aging
>   West, illiberal politics appeal to rapidly growing revisionary powers:
>   China, for example, and to some degree, India, Turkey and Iran.

Answer (score 1):

**strapped** means "short on cash".

> Dude, can you lend me $50? I'm strapped.

**debt-strapped** means "constrained by debt, having so much debt that one's options are limited".